# Why URL address is repeating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I have website hosted over [here:](http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/Login.aspx) but when I login then the url into the address bar keeps repeating and getting longer like: [this](http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/103.252.236.33/103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/User/Default.aspx) and here if you click on to the left side menu then you can see into the address bar that the URL keeps getting bigger and bigger. Please suggest me on the above why the URL is getting bigger like this?

please find the website credential as below:
username: int123
password: 123

Here is code sample:

```
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["type"] == "logout")
            {
                Session.Clear();
                Response.Cookies.Clear();
                //FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/login.aspx");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = string.Empty;
        string userid = string.Empty;
        string address = string.Empty;
        string company = string.Empty;

        if ((txtUsername.Value.Trim() == string.Empty || txtUsername.Value.Trim() == "Username") && (txtPassword.Value.Trim() == string.Empty || txtPassword.Value.Trim() == "Password"))
        {
            //divError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "Please type the correct username and password";
            ResetFields();
        }
        else if (txtUsername.Value.Trim() == string.Empty || txtUsername.Value.Trim() == "Username")
        {
            //divError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "User name is incorrect.";
            ResetFields();
        }
        else if (txtPassword.Value.Trim() == string.Empty || txtPassword.Value.Trim() == "Password")
        {
            //divError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "Password is incorrect.";
            ResetFields();
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dtuserLogin = db.GetLoginDetails(txtUsername.Value.Trim(), txtPassword.Value.Trim());
            try
            {
                if (dtuserLogin.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    userid = Convert.ToString(dtuserLogin.Rows[0]["srno"]).Trim();
                    username = Convert.ToString(dtuserLogin.Rows[0]["username"]).Trim();
                    company = Convert.ToString(dtuserLogin.Rows[0]["company"]).Trim();
                    address = Convert.ToString(dtuserLogin.Rows[0]["address"]).Trim();
                    //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username + ";" + company + ";" + address, true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in btnLogin_Click()" + ex.Message);
            }

            if (username == "admin")
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/Admin/Default.aspx", true);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/User/Default.aspx", true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ResetFields()
    {
        txtUsername.Value = "Username";
        txtPassword.Value = "Password";
    }
```

Comment: how are we meant to try and solve this without seeing any of your code?

Comment: please check my updated question. I did not provide code because this is how I code always. So, I guess this is not the code issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the code at the end of the btn click event that redirects you to that url:

```
        if (username == "admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/Admin/Default.aspx", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/User/Default.aspx", true);
        }
```

Comment: yes it is redirecting me to that URL. But it is actually repeating like this: http://103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/103.252.236.33/103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/103.252.236.33/103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/103.252.236.33/103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/103.252.236.33/103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/103.252.236.33/103.252.236.33/plesk-site-preview/2wayglobal.com/103.252.236.33/Admin/Default.aspx
based on my each clicks

Comment: the code that adds the extra part is an other page. It is not the btn in your code sample.

Comment: can you please then suggest me how do I modify the code?

Comment: No I can not. Because I do not know the code which adds the extra url parts. I guess it is in the Default.aspx button click event.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the code that is causing the issue, but I will bet $1 you are calling `Redirect` and passing what you think is an absolute URL but is actually a relative URL.  The browser is seeing the redirect as relative and simply adding on the path to the end of the URL that is already in the address bar.  It will do this over and over until the URL overflows its buffer and you get a `Bad Request` error.

Instead of

```
Response.Redirect("AbsolutePath/PageName.aspx") //This is a relative URL!
```

you should use

```
Response.Redirect("~/AbsolutePath/PageName.aspx")
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("/AbsolutePath/PageName.aspx")
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("https://ServerName.com/AbsolutePath/PageName.aspx")
```

...depending on what you are trying to accomplish.